# How to cancel pending requests in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I have an input field. When there is a keyup on this field, I send a request with AJAX and $http service of angular. My problem is when another keyup event is triggered, I need to cancel all pending requests. I have seen a lot of answers, but I have not found a solution.

I tried two things :

A service that I call

```
App.factory('findArticlesService', function($http, $q) {
   var self = this;
   self.canceller = null;

   return {
       getArticles: function(route, formData) {
           if (self.canceller) {
               self.canceler.resolve("Other request is pending");
           }

           var deferred = $q.defer();
           self.canceller = $q.defer();

           $http.post(route, angular.toJson(formData), {timeout: self.canceller.promise}).success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve({data: data}); 
           });

           return deferred.promise;
       }
   };
});

App.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 'findArticlesService', function($scope, $http, $q, findArticlesService) {
    var res = findArticlesService.getArticles(route, $scope.formData);
    console.log(res);
}]);
```

It doesn't work well.

And this :

```
var canceller = $q.defer();
canceller.resolve();

$http.post(route, angular.toJson($scope.formData), {timeout: canceller.promise}).then(function(data) {...});
```

This cancel all requests before they are sent.

Can you help me ?

Comment: what you need is debouncing, or throttling, depending on what you want to achieve.. infact ng-modal-options provides you the debounce option, so you can use that as well

Comment: I don't think that ng-model have any interactions with the $http service and Ajax requests, no ?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that, in case the trigger for Ajax calls is some user input field, then you can use ng-model-options

Comment: Else use denouncing or throttling, based on your scenario

Comment: Look Non-immediate (debounced) model updates in the form doc (v1.3.3)

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.3/docs/guide/forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are registering a factory and not a service you don't have to use 'this', your function is not going to be treated/instanciated as a constructor, with new keyword.

you need a service that maintains a canceller on every initiated request and cancels the previous request if another is sent

```
App.factory('findArticlesService', function($http, $q) {
  var canceller;

   return {
       getArticles: function(route, formData) {
           if (canceller) {
               canceller.resolve("Other request is pending");
           }
           canceller = $q.defer();

           return $http.post(route, angular.toJson(formData), {timeout: canceller.promise});

       }
   };
});
```

You don't even need an intermediary canceler, can use the same previous request as canceler

```
App.factory('findArticlesService', function($http) {
  var canceler,
      getArticles = function (route, formData) {
        if (canceler) {
          canceler.resolve('aborted');
        }
        canceler = $http.post(route, angular.toJson(formData), {timeout: canceler.promise});
        return canceler;
      };

  return {
   getArticles: getArticles
 };
});
```

Comment: Great, your first explanation works well ! Thanks :D